# Not displaying a chosen selection from a list?

Tags: c++, arrays, arraylist, text

So were being asked to make a game in my C++ class, I took a C++ class awhile ago so I am a little rusty. I remember that you can use arrays and lists?

The point of the game is to choose an army faction, choose the army type, then attack someone. Once I get to the attack part, instead of making a bunch of if statements checking for the chosen faction from the previous menu, could I implement the factions into an array from the beginning of the program and once I get to the attack stage, run through the array and compare the user chosen continent with the continents in the array and just withhold an output that matches?

If someone could post a little code or link to a website that gives an example of something like this it would be greatly appreciated, I want to do it myself, I don't really something fully typed out for me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
//  Declare variables
int menuInput = 0, continentInput = 0, armyInput = 0, actionInput = 0;

//  Intro
cout << "WELCOME TO WAR" << endl;

//  Display main menu
do {
    cout << "1) Rules" << endl;
    cout << "2) Play Game" << endl;
    cout << "3) Quit" << endl;
    cout << "Menu choice: ";
    cin >> menuInput;


    //  if rules is selected
    if (menuInput == 1) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "RULES: " << endl;
        cout << "1) Choose your player." << endl;
        cout << "2) Choose your army type." << endl;
        cout << "3) Choose to attack." << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }

    //  if game is selected
    else if (menuInput == 2) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "START" << endl;

        //  first do while loop, continent choice
        do {
            cout << "1) North America" << endl;
            cout << "2) South America" << endl;
            cout << "3) Europe" << endl;
            cout << "4) Africa" << endl;
            cout << "5) Asia" << endl;
            cout << "6) Australia" << endl;
            cout << "7) Antartica" << endl;
            cout << "Choose your player from the list: ";
            cin >> continentInput;
            cout << endl;
            // invalid display if selection not in range
            if (continentInput <= 0 ||continentInput > 7) {
                cout << "INVALID" << endl;
                cout << endl;
            }
        } while (continentInput <= 0 || continentInput > 8);

        //  second do while loop, army type choice
        do {
            cout << "1) Army (Ground type forces)" << endl;
            cout << "2) Navy (Sea type forces)" << endl;
            cout << "3) Air Force (Air type forces)" << endl;
            cout << "Choose your army type from the list: ";
            cin >> armyInput;
            cout << endl;

            if (armyInput <= 0 || armyInput > 3) {
                cout << "INVALID" << endl;
            }
        } while (armyInput <= 0 || armyInput > 3);

        // third do while loop, who to attack


    }
    else if (menuInput == 3) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "GAME OVER" << endl;
    }

    else {
        //  display invlaid input if number choice is not in given range
        cout << "INAVLID INPUT" << endl;
    }

} while (menuInput != 3);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Have you learned classes yet? It'd be better if you had a class object that had a player and army type members, that you set, get, and then act on. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_classes_objects.htm

Comment: @DigitalNinja the class hasn't gotten to that point yet, the first "version" is supposed to be coded in a more basic way, but that is what I had in plans for as far as object orientated.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your user input to a number you can reference an array filled with the choices.

```
military[x] = { "Army", "Navy" ...};
fromWhere[x] = { "North America", "South" ...};
toKill[x] = { "Whoever has oil" ... };
//get user input.
//toKill[get user input];
//kill with military[get user input];
//kill form fromWhere[get user input];
//do some attack logic
```

Just a heads up your question is rather vague.  Can you clarify what you need. It seems you wish to hash your values and do a quick lookup to avoid string comparison but you don't need to because you are grabbing an `int` as user input.

Comment: So once I get to the attack stage of the game, I want a list to pop up of the other continents you can choose to attack, minus the continent you chose, the one your "playing" as right now. So I was confused on how to code it with the way my program is now. I have the user's input on their continent but since the other choices are not in the program I was looking for input on ways to compare the user choice with the list. I'm going to try what you said with making the choices a list and run a for loop once I get to the menu for attack, maybe that will work.